# Баг при делении на ноль

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начну из далека. Писал калькулятор, и до определённого момента у меня при делении на `0` выводило `Error` (как и должно было), но почему-то позже это перестало работать и при делении на `0` у меня всё зависает, я так понимаю, что происходит жесткая утечка памяти. Вот код, который отвечает за математическую часть:

```
$('.result').click(function(){
    console.log('In')
    if(inputLength != 0){

        try {
           let result = eval($('.input-field').text());
           $('.input-field').html('').append(+result.toFixed(10));
           inputLength = countDigits(result);
        }catch(e) {
            $('.input-field').html('Error');
            inputLength = 5;
        } // end catch
    }
}); // end click
```

Принцип такой. Есть поле `input-field`, куда при клике на клавиши добавляются символы (например `5+2` и т.д). При клике на клавишу `result`, `js` считывает значение поля `input-field` и выполняет код благодаря `eval` (Да да, `eval is evil`, но всё же :D) так же есть `try{}catch{}`, что бы при вводе `5+` выводило ошибку. Сам вопрос: Почему при делении на ноль происходит какая-то дичь?

---

P.S: Вот сам [калькулятор](https://catinears.github.io/Calculator/)

Comment: `eval($('.input-field').text())` ))))))) ну вы даете

Comment: Ну тут как минимум JS должен вернуть `Infinity` при делении на ноль, у вас почему-то клик обрабатывается два раза, методом вывода `console.log` поищите причину двойного выполнения вычислений.

Comment: Нашёл в чем дело, у вас в функцию `countDigits(n)` приходит `"Infinity"` и происходит зависание, добавьте исключение или проверку чтобы `n` было обязательно числом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильный ответ дал **Дмитрий Горный** в комментариях.

в функцию `countDigits(n)` приходит `"Infinity"` и происходит зависание, нужно добавить исключение или проверку, чтобы n было обязательно числом.